# How to create a progress bar that the color change according to percentation

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

How to create a progress bar that the color change according to percentation
I want to change the bar's color to change smoothly according to value given (js & css)

ex: 0% = green, 100% = red, 75% = orange (gradient between red and green)
This code in css :

```
<style>
#myBar {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ff0000;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 1em;
    animation: color 2s linear 0s alternate;
}

@keyframes color{
    0% {background-color: #0f0;}
    50% {background-color: #ff0;}
    100% {background-color: #f00;}
}
</style>
```

This code in file index.php :

```
<script>
function move() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
    var newElem = document.getElementById("percent");
    var height = 1;
    score = <?php echo($percentation);?>;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 25);

    function frame() {
        if (height >= score) {
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            height++;
            elem.style.height = height + '%';
            newElem.innerHTML = height + '%';
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

myBar is div of the loading bar itself
percent is div to output the value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do pure CSS. Here is an example

```css
.progressBar {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  
}


.progress {
    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    animation: color 5s linear 0s alternate;
}

@keyframes color{
    10% {
    background-color: #0f0;
    width: 20%;/*At 10%, change the width to 20%*/
    }
    40% {
    background-color: #ff0;
    width: 40%;
    }
    70% {
    background-color: #f00;
    width: 60%;
    }
    100% {
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="progressBar">
    <div class="progress">
    
    </div>
</div>
```

What the idea is? You change the width or height through the keyframes.

Here is an example using height like you asked.

```css
.progressBar {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  width: 20px;
  height: 200px;
  
}


.progress {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    background-color: blue;
    animation: color 5s linear 0s alternate;
}

@keyframes color{
    10% {
    background-color: #0f0;
    height: 20%;/*At 10%, change the height to 20%*/
    }
    40% {
    background-color: #ff0;
    height: 40%;
    }
    70% {
    background-color: #f00;
    height: 60%;
    }
    100% {
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="progressBar">
    <div class="progress">
      
    </div>
</div>
```